# Show custom module configuration in Admin Menu not in Store -> Setting -> Configuration

Tags: configuration, magento2.2, adminmenu

I am creating a custom module , now wanted to add module configuration options like `enable/disable options` . I found many post that shows how to create these options using `system.xml` but in that way it add the option in `Store -> Setting -> Configuration`

Till now i am able to crate configuration section In `Store -> Setting -> Configuration` as shown below.

[image: configuration]

Any one share any post or link in which i can learn how to create these options in module admin menu pages not in `Configuration` page.

I am trying to create same sections in my `module page` as we have in `Magento 1.9.x`
[image: admin page]

In  `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/CompanyName/ReviewRating/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="reviewrating" translate="label" sortOrder="10000">
            <label>Reviewrating</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="reviewrating" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>reviewrating</label>
            <tab>reviewrating</tab>
            <resource>CompanyName_ReviewRating::reviewrating</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Item creation by schedule</label>
                <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="cron_expression" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Add Item Cron Expression</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/CompanyName/ReviewRating/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="CompanyName_ReviewRating::parent" title="ReviewRating" 
             module="CompanyName_ReviewRating" sortOrder="100" 
             resource="CompanyName_ReviewRating::parent"/>

        <add id="CompanyName_ReviewRating::index" title="ReviewRating Index" 
             module="CompanyName_ReviewRating" sortOrder="10" 
             action="reviewrating/index" resource="CompanyName_ReviewRating::index" 
              parent="CompanyName_ReviewRating::parent"/>

         <add id="CompanyName_ReviewRating::settings" title="Settings" module="CompanyName_ReviewRating" sortOrder="30" action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/reviewrating/" resource="CompanyName_ReviewRating::settings"/>   
    </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: where want to add your configuration key under which tab I send you the code to put in the system.xml

Comment: @MohamedElMrabet sir i updated my question , may be now its clear what i am trying to achieve. Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you have to add menu for your module's configuration in `menu.xml` 
file, you can add below code in your `menu.xml` to add link of your module's configuration

```
<add id="Namespace_Module::settings" title="Settings" module="Namespace_Module" parent="Namespace_Module::your_parent_menu_id" sortOrder="30" action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/your_section_id/" resource="Namespace_Module::settings"/>
```

Comment: can you please explain how to use it.

Comment: have you created menu.xml in you module?

Comment: yes i posted above, i copied it , no mush details how it works currently

Comment: you just have to change Namespace_Module, section id, resource and parent id from above code

Comment: section id you will get in your system.xml file

Comment: what is your_parent_menu_id

Comment: it is for adding a submenu, you can remove it if you don't have parent menu

Comment: in your code of menu.xml you have used parent_id for Index menu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69152/discussion-between-saurabh-ranjan-and-piyush).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below link to show custom module configuration in Admin Menu in Magento2 -

https://github.com/jainmegha5395/system-config