# Module Configuration From Admin Menu as a Seperate page without side menu

Tags: magento2

[Show custom module configuration in Admin Menu not in Store -> Setting -> Configuration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202781/show-custom-module-configuration-in-admin-menu-not-in-store-setting-config/202850#202850)

Can we display the configuration without side menu in a seperate page from admin menu.

And the configurations should not be a grid, need to display the fields one by one as the general configurations display.